# When is deleting a question good, and when is it bad?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I just was banned from asking more questions. [This post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th/255584#255584) answers the question about how to improve my existing questions.

It seems it counts deleting a post a bad action which itself may lead to a ban. However, sometimes I gained some reputation and a badge named "Peer Pressure" by deleting a question. (It was closed however.)

Then I got confused about whether deleting a question is a good or bad action, or when it's counted good and when its counted bad?

What about closed posts? Should I leave them or is it good to delete them? Is deleting them counted as an improvement? I know deleted questions are taken into account for banning a user because they have wasted some people's time. But what about now: keep them or delete them? What about closed question which already have an answer?

Comment: Keep a question when it represents a contribution to the collective wisdom of the world. (Or stackoverflow). And if it doesn't, it's noise and lowering the average.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You only got reputation because the votes *removing* reputation were removed with the deleted question. The peer pressure badge encourages you to do the right thing with a bad post, but by no means is intended to encourage you to write a bad post and subsequently delete it.

Its *always* a bad thing to delete (though you sometimes you have to). If a question is deleted within 30 days of posting, it still counts against the question-ban. A high percentage of deleted posts also is a factor (the actual algorithm is secret).

If a post is closed; *fix it*. Fix the deleted ones as well (and un-delete)! Only delete if a post is truly unsalvageable. Closed questions with an answer often *can't* be deleted; even if they can, consider leaving them for future users if the answers are good.

Also good advice: [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

To answer your question about how to edit, here are some ideas (based on common problems I see in questions now):

- Make the title very specific, and a question if possible
- Re-structure the question so the problem statement is very clear. If you were *missing* a problem statement, add one! Make sure *you are actually asking a question*.
- If you had a giant code dump, or no code at all, make your provided code sample encompass the scope of the problem without making us read through pages of code. *Most* questions should have code, if yours doesn't, make sure it doesn't need it.
- Remove any rants/complaints; it just annoys the very people you are trying to have re-open/upvote/answer your question
- Fix any grammar you can (IIRC you aren't a native english speaker). It may not be fair, but questions written in correct technical/professional English get a much better response. Having complete sentences and paragraphs is good!

Whatever you do; **don't** be a chameleon question. If your edit changes what you asked, you've done it wrong.

As for off-topic questions; these mostly are unsalvageable (so do delete). The following caveats, where you should edit, do apply:

- If you were asking for resources, but that wasn't actually the point of the question; remove any such references so the question is actually answerable.
- If you got the **"Why isn't this code working"** close reason, do what it says. Add a clear problem statement, the code showing the problem, and what you expected it to do.

Comment: Thank you, you may want to answer my last update about closed questions with answer, I think its also when deleting is bad.

Comment: I also mentioned the link you gave in my question, it may also needs these clarification.

Comment: Also I felt reopening a closed question is very hard. or maybe mods are reluctant to do that. then I really didn't know what to do with them when I hadn't much hope.

Comment: @Ahmad Editing a closed question automatically puts it in the re-open queue (and bumps it to the top of the active pages). Its no guarantee that it will be reopened (you need 5 reopen votes), but it will be looked at.

Comment: I may can edit some of my questions to gain up-votes for example to hide or delete some parts about trivial things. But I found it against the spirit of the comments below the question. or maybe some points in some answers. Should I do that?

Comment: @Ahmad **Absolutely**. Don't *change* the question, but if you can clarify, make the formatting better, fix your grammar, whatever; **do it**. Making your post better is the *purpose* of editing, the fact that it gets you re-open/upvotes is a nice side-effect. Basically, if you can make a **good** edit; do it all the time, every time.

Comment: Yes I don't change the question in a way the answers seem irrelevant, just maybe some comments? Also about a closed question, when its off-topic I can't do anything to save it unless change the question?! or deleting it. So deleting it is better right?

Comment: @Ahmad I tried to address your recent comments in an edit to my post. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: @Ahmad One other piece of advice; if you want to know what *good* questions look like, go to the homepage and look at all the upvoted ones; even go look at the questions I've posted, or another high-rep user has posted. For mine, none were hits, but they are all 0+ score as well.